# x++ alternative IDE?

Tags: ide, x++

I'm looking at taking a possible contract role as an MS Dynamics developer. In the interim, I'd like to play around with x++. Am I right in thinking that the only code editor available is the one that ships with AX?

I'd really like a freebie alternative to use for now, but I haven't come across one.

Comment: You are correct. Some objects in AX are developed in Visual Studio, but you still need a connection to AX. You could write code somewhere else, but you wouldn't be able to compile or build anything without the AX client.

Comment: Ak ok. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can get something for free, but you can create a dynamics ax instance accessible from the web, with microsoft lifecycle services.

https://lcs.dynamics.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can also ask your new Company to download a demo VM for you. It's available on the Customer and on the Partner Source.

https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/downloads/service-packs/AX2012DemoToolsMaterials

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, besides MorphX, the native IDE in MS Dynamics, and Visual Studio(for C# dev), you don't have much of a choice.
However, there a portal called 365 Talent portal, where you can register as a freelance MS Dynamics Developer and request for an access to the Dynamics Learning Portal (DLP). 
Finally , after your access to the DLP is granted, you can play around with some VMs(with AX installed), read documentation, etc.